# Resetting file handler name in python logging

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I have a code structure that looks like this:

```
.
├── scripts
│   └── test.py
└── utils
    ├── __init__.py
    └── lib.py
```

In my `utils/__init__.py` file I've set up logging like so:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
ch = logging.FileHandler("logfile", mode="w")
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter(
    "%(levelname)s:%(name)s:[%(funcName)s]:%(message)s", "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"
)
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(ch)
```

This works, and if I log in `lib.py` using code like so

```
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def a_function():
    LOGGER.info('This works')
```

then everything runs and gets logged.

However, I often find myself wanting to run different scripts while in the same environment and I'd like to have a log that's named differently for each run (I don't want them writing over each other or appending to the same log). What is the best way to modify the logging name when logging is set up like this? I've tried doing things like the following in `scripts/test.py`:

```
import logging

from utils.lib import a_function


def main():
    # rename handler
    fh = logging.FileHandler("logfile2", "w")
    formatter = logging.Formatter(
        "%(levelname)s:%(name)s:[%(funcName)s]:%(message)s", "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"
    )
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    log = logging.getLogger()
    log.handlers.clear()
    log.addHandler(fh)

    a_function()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This works in *adding* a new log called logfile2, but I still get logging in the original logfile. I would have thought that the `log.handlers.clear()` command would have cleared that out.

What am I doing wrong here?